# Collective Index or Individual index which is fastest for data accessing

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table having 22 fields or Attributes namely `Geo, Theater, Area, TotalSales` etc.

I want to get `TotalSales` may be for a `Geo` or a `Theater` or an `Area` or maybe
for a particular `theater` of a particular `Geo` and so on.

The table consists of almost `302245` records

So, how to index it for faster access?
Should I put an Index individually on each of the field namely `geo`, `theater`

or,

Should I put an index on all 22 fields collectively like,
`index on (geo, theater, area, TotalSales... and so on)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite `INDEX(geo, theater, area, ...)` would only help if the *first* column (`geo`, in this example) were included in the `WHERE` clause.  So that is not a good candidate.

22 separate indexes on each column is an ugly possibility, but may be close to 'best'.

Indexing a "flag" column (yes/no, M/F, ON/OFF, etc) is almost always useless.  In general, if the index isn't going to limit the resultset to less than about 20% of the table, the Optimizer will decide that a table scan is faster than bouncing back and forth between the index and the data.  So, this reduces the 22 by eliminating any low-cardinality columns.

On the other hand, 'composite' indexes are often good, even if they include a flag.  You mentioned `INDEX(geo, theater)` -- This would be very good if both are specified, and would also be good if only `geo` were specified in the `WHERE`.  (It is useless if only `theater` is specified`.)  So, instead of 22 single-column indexes, think about 22 two-column indexes, where each of the 22 columns occurs once as the *first* column in the index.

But...  Well, I don't want to copy my entire blog here, so let me send you to [*my index cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) to discover how to make 'good' indexes.

But... That begs the issue of how many to make.  22 is "too many".  At some point, the overhead of more indexes will outweigh the benefit.  I suggest you look at what people are *usually* asking.  Then make optimal indexes for the dozen most popular queries.

Comment: Thank you for help. But a `WHERE` clause in my DB either contains only `Geo`, or only `Theater` or only `Area`, or may be a combination of any two out of three, or even any three or four our 22 columns.